# Select a html data-attribute with a specific value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

The html code

```
<div id="slider">
    <?php
    while($gal = mysql_fetch_assoc($gallerydb))
        {?>
        <img data-store="<? echo $gal["ImageID"] ?>" src="SiteAdministration/ControlCenter/Gal/<? echo $gal["ImgPfad"] ?>"><?
        }?>
</div>
```

The jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('#slider img[data-store='" + 2 + "']').fadeIn(300);

});
```

The html code shows a div with a while construct, that gets all images from a specific folder and adds an ID out of a database(numbers).

The jQuery code shows my attempt to select a img with a specific data-attribute value.

The problem is, that the img won't fade in, I suggest I messed up the selector.

**Another question would be, how can I make it work, so that the selector starts with the lowest ID numer and ends with the highest, because the ID's can change.**

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

To solve my changing ID problem I just created another variable which increases automatically. If someone wants to know a solution.

```
<div id="slider">
    <?php
    $id = 1;
    while($gal = mysql_fetch_assoc($gallerydb))
        {?>
        <img data-store="<? echo $id++ ?>" src="SiteAdministration/ControlCenter/Gal/<? echo $gal["ImgPfad"] ?>"><?
        }?>
</div>
```

---

```
sliderStart = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#slider img[data-store="' + 1 + '"]').fadeIn(300);
startSlider();

});

function startSlider(){

count = $('#slider img').size();

loop = setInterval(function(){

    if(sliderNext > count) {        
        sliderNext = 1;
        sliderStart = 1;        
    }

    $('#slider img').fadeOut(300);
    $('#slider img[data-store="' + sliderNext + '"]').fadeIn(300);

    sliderStart = sliderNext;
    sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;

}, 3000)

}
```

Comment: You have quote mismatch. Do `$('#slider img[data-store="' + 2 + '"]').fadeIn(300);` Look at your console for clues.

Comment: jesus christ.... time to take a break I guess... -.- Thank you very much :)
Any idea how the get the min/max ID thing done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What PSL said, your doubles and singles are the wrong way around.

Also, I would not use hyphens in your custom html attributes.

Comment: What's wrong with using hyphens? Any idea how to get the second question working?

Comment: _"i would not use hyphens in your custom html attributes"_? Why? That's a valid HTML5 `data-*` attribute.

Comment: strictly there is no reason.. but for ease.. a js object containing different attributes you wish to deploy to the html, if the the attributes contain hyphens then the name of each object must be enclosed in quotes without then a simple object might look like:  obj = [{data_store:123),{another:345}]. seems like a small optimisation, but when you build a big app this small step saves time.

Comment: oh and it also makes it a lot easier to call them out too.. obj.data_store is easier than obj['data-store']

Comment: That's true, I even write underline-based CSS classes, but that's not the case for the `data-*` attributes. If you want to use underline you can write `data-my_identifier` which is a valid data attribute but not `data_my_identifier`.